# Get list of lists from query parameters using flask_restx RequestParser

Tags: python, rest, flask, query-string, flask-restplus

I am creating Python server using Flask and Flask-RESTX modules. I would like to define route e. g. for this URL:

```
/users?sort=age,asc&sort=name,desc
```

So when I read `sort` query parameter, I will have list of pairs, where each pair is `(property, order)` where order is `asc` or `desc`. I have following code:

```
from flask_restx import Resource
from flask import request
from flask_restx import reqparse

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument("sort", type=str)


@api.route("/users")
class Users(Resource):

    @api.marshal_list_with(...)
    @api.expect(parser)
    def get(self):
        print(request.args.getlist("sort"))
```

The code prints `['age,asc', 'name,desc']` which is fine, however I have to manually split values by comma and check if there are only 2 values (e. g. `age` and `asc`) in each item.

Is there any better way to handle this?

Answer (score 3):

Add `action` argument with value: `'split'` for the RequestParser to get a splitted list of values.

And get values form parsed arguments dictionary.

Your example given my comment:

```
from flask_restx import Resource
from flask import request
from flask_restx import reqparse

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument("sort", type=str, action="split")


@api.route("/users")
class Users(Resource):

    @api.marshal_list_with(...)
    @api.expect(parser)
    def get(self):
        print(parser.parse_args()["sort"])
```

The result should look like this:

```
[['age', 'asc'], ['name', 'desc']]
```

Comment: For whoever stumbles on this keep in mind  request parser is deprecated and a library like marshmallow is recommended instead: https://flask-restx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parsing.html